# converting apache htaccess to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to convert apache htaccess rule to nginx config but it is not working. Following are the details of rules and nginx config:

**.htaccess Rule**

`RewriteBase /`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

**Nginx Config For Above**

```
server {

    listen      ip_address:80;

    server_name  www.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;

    root   /var/www/html/example.com/;

    index  index.php;

location / {

                if (!-e $request_filename){

                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 break;

}

}
```

when i access website it opens home page and when i click other menus it gives 404 not found.

Following is the error log:

`2015/03/18 05:31:56 [error] 3550#0: *7 open() "/var/www/html/example/index.php//contents.html" failed (20: Not a directory), client:`

`1.2.3.4, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /contents.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"`

any ideas???

Shoaib..

Comment: /var/log/nginx/hostname.com-error.log can make it clear what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved, we enabled following in website's config.php file,

`$config['index_page'] = '';
 $config['uri_protocol']       = 'REQUEST_URI';`

And nginx config as follows,

`location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}`

it worked...

Thanks @Denis and @SuddenHead for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx rewrite is wrong – because of the slash in the end, nginx thinks index.php is a folder. You could do something like:

```
location / {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
            }
}
```

And then in your PHP code parse $_REQUEST['url']

Another possibility, many webmasters are doing it this way:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Meaning – try to open a file first (if it exists), try to open a folder (if it exists), last resort – pass it to index.php. $args will contain query string, you can access original URL through $_SERVER.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Denis. I used it earlier but it was not working for other links on the website and there were no errors in the log file. same as my current rules. home page works fine but when i click other links it doen't work.

Comment: @Shoaib what are your links like? Can you give 1-2 examples?

Comment: sure it like, 

http://example.com (Home page)

http://example.com/members.html (actual url shows currently on apache for members page)

Comment: @Shoaib and your Apache rewrite rule (RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]) is working? It's not supposed to work, actually :)

Comment: it is working. when i disable that rule it gives 404 not found. I have talked to developer he said that on this website router.php file does rest of rewriting. we will dig out issue together.